# UITextField Target/Action vs Delegate Methods

Tags: ios, delegates, uitextfield, target-action, rubymotion

I used to use XCode the develop my apps and using that; I could create a link up in IB/Storyboard that synthesized this methods:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents: (UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

for when

However, no I'm doing it all programmatically (in rubymotion, though not necessarily relevant) and looking into the documentation for UITextField I found some delegate methods, which I implemented as follows:

```
def textFieldShouldReturn(text_field)
  text_field.resignFirstResponder
end

def textFieldShouldEndEditing(text_field)
  # this is for validations; don't set a first responder here
  true
end

def textFieldDidEndEditing(text_field)
  text_field == @email_field ? @password_field.becomeFirstResponder : delegate.validate_login_info
end
```

But using this, I found that I could not tab through the input fields (of which I have two; email and password) as I could before with the addTarget approach.

What is the difference between these two approaches? Does the former implement the latter behind the scenes? I don't understand why one will allow me to tab through and the other won't. Did I just implement the delegate methods differently than the target/action approach does behind the scenes?

Feedback appreciated,
pachun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with target/action. I am assuming you mean in Interface Builder you would drag from the `UITextField` to the `File's Owner` and select delegate from the HUD.

Doing the above would have the effect of assigning the textField's delegate which you would need to do in code like this

```
@email_field.delegate    = self
@password_field.delegate = self
```

the above is assuming that the class that creates the `UITextField`'s will act as their delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any difference between delegation and target/action in this case,but with delegation this way works:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.firstTextField)
    {
        [self.secondTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.secondTextField)
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        // proceed with login
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Validation
    return YES;
}
```

Regards